# ForEach loop in Swift to use content of 2D array

Tags: foreach, swiftui

I want to use a ForEach loop, but it doesn't work.

```
let navigation = [["Kunde", "person"], ["Wartung", "gear"]]


NavigationView {
    List {
        NavigationLink(destination: ListView(title: "Kunde")) {
            Label("Kunde", systemImage: "person")
        }
        NavigationLink(destination: ListView(title: "Wartung")) {
            Label("Wartung", systemImage: "gear")
        }
        // MANY MORE
    }
}
```

My approach prints the numbers from 0 to 7, but I want the contents of the array.

My approach:

```
let navigation = [["Kunde", "person"], ["Wartung", "gear"]]


NavigationView {
    List {
        ForEach(navigation.indices) { index in
            NavigationLink(destination: ListView(title: "\(index)")) {
                Label("\(self.index)", systemImage: "\(index)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only giving the `index`. You could do `navigation[index][0]` for example to get the title, but this is quite tedious.

A better way is to create a custom type, plus it will also be `Identifiable` so it's safer to use on a mutating list of items.

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private let navigation = [
        NavigatableView("Kunde", image: "person"),
        NavigatableView("Wartung", image: "gear")
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(navigation) { newView in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ListView(title: newView.title)) {
                        Label(newView.title, systemImage: newView.image)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct NavigatableView: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
    let image: String

    init(_ title: String, image: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.image = image
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to stick with your first version because it is shorter. THX!

Comment: @Nikolass Shorter code doesn't mean better code. You will have animation issues if you change `navigation` since you are identifying by index rather than a unique identifier. It's also not particular safe, because these arrays could be an unpredictable size.